# File not found error while specifying windows path

Tags: python, windows, directory

I face a curious problem while specifying file in dicom. The file is present but I keep getting 'File not found error'. I am able to read another file ('xx.csv') in the same location without any problem. Please help.

```
path = r'D:\REGI\siim\dicom-images-train\1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.300.1517875162.258080\1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.300.1517875162.258079'
print(os.listdir(path))
```

output: ['1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.300.1517875162.258081.dcm', 'xx.csv']

```
yy = os.path.join(path, '1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.300.1517875162.258081.dcm')
yy1 = os.path.join(path, 'xx.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(yy1)
ds = dicom.dcmread(yy)
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-90d18af3b900> in <module>
      5 yy1 = os.path.join(path, 'xx.csv')
      6 df = pd.read_csv(yy1)
----> 7 ds = dicom.dcmread(yy)
      8 os.listdir(path)

E:\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py in dcmread(fp, defer_size, stop_before_pixels, force, specific_tags)
    845         except Exception:
    846             logger.debug("Reading file '{0}'".format(fp))
--> 847         fp = open(fp, 'rb')
    848 
    849     if config.debugging:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\REGI\\siim\\dicom-images-train\\1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.300.1517875162.258080\\1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.300.1517875162.258079\\1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.300.1517875162.258081.dcm'
```

Comment: Check the file path via `os.stat(yy)`, which will confirm whether the file exists and is accessible. If the `stat` call fails, the exception will include a Windows error code, which may be more helpful since several Windows errors map to POSIX `ENOENT`.

Answer (score 1):

with try and failure I found than if you use a path with more than 258 (counting the fullpath) characters you get this error on windows.

and work using a shorest one

Answer (score 0):

Check privileges too. May be you don't have access to the file.